# Creating a Sublime Text 3 Custom Syntax - matching words after keyword

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I'm trying to create some simple custom highlighting in Sublime Text 3 using AAAPackageDev.

In the line
`void plastic my_material`,
I'd like to match `plastic`, i.e. the material type, as a keyword and `my_material`, i.e. the material name, as a string.

I've got the following which however only matches `plastic` and not the name that follows, i.e. `my_material`:

```
// [PackageDev] target_format: plist, ext: tmLanguage
{ "name":       "Radiance",
  "scopeName":  "source.radiance",
  "fileTypes":  ["rad", "sky", "mat"],
  "uuid": "885b4450-d2bb-4a67-aea0-ceb5a0554630",

  "patterns": [
    {
        "name": "keyword.source.radiance",
        "match": "\\bplastic\\b | \\blight\\b"
    },
    {
    "name": "keyword.source.radiance",
    "begin": "(\\bplastic\\b | \\blight\\b)",
    "patterns": [
        { "include": "$self"},
        {
          "name": "string.source.radiance",
          "match": "[^\\s]+"
        }],
    "end": "\\n"
    }]
}
```

I'm trying to follow [these docs here](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html). Any ideas?

**EDIT**

The full text I'm trying to parse is:

```
void plastic my_material
0
0
5 0.4 0.25 0.05 0.05 0.03
```

`void` and `plastic` maintain position but might change their value. `my_material` is just an arbitrary name that could comprise pretty much anything but must follow a keyword from the first pattern and will be followed by a new line.

Comment: Have you tried removing the spaces around the pipe character (`|`) in your regex? That might be causing the problems.

Comment: Thanks @Revan, just tried that but it doesn't seem to make it work...

Comment: My input is `void plastic my_material`

Comment: you mean this http://regex101.com/r/dI1xA7/7 ?

Comment: Is that it? That's the only string you're passing into the regex? Is it always going to be the second and third word? Or is it always "`plastic`"?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I'm certainly no expert in regex and not totally sure about your link. I'd like to have `plastic` or another word from the first pattern being recognised as a keyword and whatever word that follows after a valid keyword as a string

Comment: You seem to making a distinction between `keyword` and `string` but regex can't do that. It will take in an input string and give back matches in the form of strings

Comment: @skamazin This is for Sublime Text 3 's custom syntax. The problem is that the above doesn't seem to recognise the word after the keyword and I'm totally lost why not... so it's not a pure regex problem but how to use regex to create a ST3 custom syntax...

Comment: I didn't realize you were using this for custom syntax highlight. My fault for not reading the question thoroughly